# How to convert Java into Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

I don't know if somebody has already answered this question. If it's the case, then, please for the redondancy.

I would like to transform this function into Kotlin function. Thanks for the help.

```
private final static String HEX = "XXXXXXXXX";
private static void appendHex(StringBuffer sb, byte b) {
    sb.append(HEX.charAt((b>>4)&0x0f)).append(HEX.charAt(b&0x0f));
}
```

Comment: could it be that `HEX` actually rather contains something like `0123456789ABCDEF`? if so... what about: `String.format("%02X", b)` instead?

Comment: @Roland. Yes it contains. But it is the content of the function that is very important to me!

Comment: I am not sure whether I understood you correctly... `sb.append(HEX.charAt((b>>4)&0x0f)).append(HEX.charAt(b&0x0f));` is what you want to translate to Kotlin right? But if it is already simplifiable to `sb.append(String.format("%02X", b))`, that's not ok for you?

Comment: ok. i see what you claim. That's ok too.

Comment: There's a chance that you want to keep this static function in Java so that you can still keep using `Byte` with `>>`.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using an extension function for that:

```
private const val HEX = "XXXXXXXXX"
fun StringBuffer.appendHex(b: Byte): StringBuffer {
    val i = b.toInt()
    append(HEX[i shr 4 and 0x0f])
    append(HEX[i and 0x0f])
    return this
}
```

I also made the function return `this` again so you can even call it in a chain:

```
myStringBuffer
   .append(someThing)
   .appendHex(myByte)
   .append(someThingElse)
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's just a hex string representation you need (and that's also what I get from your comment), you may just want to use the following instead:

```
fun StringBuffer.appendHex(b : Byte) = append("%02X".format(b))
```

Usage is then the same as also Lino has shown:

```
StringBuffer()
    .append("some text")
    .appendHex(someByte)
```

or if you need to keep your current signature:

```
companion object {
  @JvmStatic
  fun appendHex(s : StringBuffer, b : Byte) {
    s.append("%02X".format(b))
  }
}
```

Comment: You could also use `"%02X".format(b)`, which does the exact same as `String.format()`

Comment: @Lino thanks! didn't know that one ;-) but to be honest, I didn't even care so far as I used a static import for the `String.format` and that was already short enough ;-) but I will remember now ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
companion object {
    private const val HEX = "XXXXXXXXX"

    @JvmStatic
    private fun appendHex(sb: StringBuffer, b: Int) {
        sb.append(HEX[b shr 4 and 0x0f]).append(HEX[b and 0x0f])
    }
}
```

Please note that I had to change the `Byte` to `Int`, because `Byte` doesn't seem to have `shr` and `and` defined for some unknown reason.

No, I really don't know why bitwise operators would not be defined over *byte*.